# How to check if a value exists in table or not in Java?

Tags: java, oracle

Can anyone suggest me that how can I check if value entered by user is exist in some specific table or not through javaCode?

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing you need the [JDBC tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html) first of all. That will enable you to run SQL against your DB from Java such as:

```
if EXISTS (select *
    from authors
    where name = 'Dan Brown')
```